# What is wrong in my code if saving an info in Firebase database brings "App keeps stopping"

Tags: android

When clicking on button(bSave) and trying to save Name, Age and Id in realtime firebase database, app keeps stopping. Maybe the problem is with the connection between app and firebase ?

RegisterAcitivity

```
package com.example.mher.loginregister;

import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.firebase.auth.AuthResult;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;

import java.security.cert.CertPathBuilderSpi;

public class RegisterActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private EditText etAge;
private EditText etName;
private EditText etEmail;
private EditText etPassword;
private Button bRegister;
private Button bSave;
private ProgressDialog progressDialog;
private FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth;
DatabaseReference databaseDrivers;


protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_register);

    firebaseAuth=FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

    progressDialog=new ProgressDialog(this);

    etAge=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.etAge);
    etName=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.etName);
    etEmail=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.etEmail);
    etPassword=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.etPassword);
    bRegister=(Button) findViewById(R.id.bRegister);
    bSave=(Button) findViewById(R.id.bSave);
    databaseDrivers= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();


    bSave.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            adddriver();
        }
    });




    bRegister.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            registeruser();

        }
    });



}
private void adddriver()
{
    String name=etName.getText().toString().trim();
    String age=etAge.getText().toString().trim();
    if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(name))
    {
        String id=databaseDrivers.push().getKey();
        Driver driver=new Driver(id,name,age);
        databaseDrivers.child(id).setValue(driver);


    }
    else
    {
        Toast.makeText(this,"Please enter a name",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
    }
}
private void registeruser()
{
    String email=etEmail.getText().toString().trim();
    String password=etPassword.getText().toString().trim();
    if(TextUtils.isEmpty(email))
    {
        Toast.makeText(this,"Please Enter Your Email",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return;

    }
    if(TextUtils.isEmpty(password))
    {
        Toast.makeText(this,"Please Enter Your Password",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return;

    }
    progressDialog.setMessage("Registering User");
    progressDialog.show();
    firebaseAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email,password).addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
            if(task.isSuccessful())
            {
                Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this,"Registered Successfully",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                progressDialog.hide();
            }
            else
            {
                Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this,"Could Not Register Successfully",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                progressDialog.hide();
            }

        }
    });

}
```

}

Driver Class

```
package com.example.mher.loginregister;

public class Driver {
String DriverId;
String DriverName;
String DriverAge;
public Driver()
{

}

public Driver(String driverId, String driverName, String driverAge) {
    DriverId = driverId;
    DriverName = driverName;
    DriverAge = driverAge;
}

public String getDriverId() {
    return DriverId;
}

public String getDriverName() {
    return DriverName;
}

public String getDriverAge() {
    return DriverAge;
}
}
```

Comment: Use LogCat to examine the Java stack trace associated with your crash: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173/unfortunately-myapp-has-stopped-how-can-i-solve-this

Answer (score 0):

I think it is because this:

```
String id=databaseDrivers.push().getKey();
Driver driver=new Driver(id,name,age);
databaseDrivers.child(id).setValue(driver);
```

`getKey()` retrieves value from server, so `databaseDrivers.child(id).setValue(driver);` must wait before it is done and it causes a freeze.

Try this:

```
DatabaseReference newPostRef = databaseDrivers.push(); 
newPostRef.setValue(driver);
```

or simplier:

```
databaseDrivers.push().setValue(driver);
```

This way you can't add an id to your driver object, but you don't need it because it is stored as a key to your value (driver).